# [SOLVED] Arduino ethernet communication with ROS

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-kinetic, rosserial-arduino, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I'm looking from a package to communicate btw arduino and ROS kinetic (on jetson) with an arduino ethernet module.

I need to send msg / srv from arduino to the jetson.

Tim

---

Update:

I found a file [ArduinoTcpHardware.h](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/melodic-devel/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ArduinoTcpHardware.h) in the rosserial github. Anyone know how to use it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310148/%5Bsolved%5D-arduino-ethernet-communication-with-ros/) by [Tim Nicolas](https://answers.ros.org/users/38875/tim-nicolas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So finally I found a solution.

I use [this example](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/melodic-devel/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/examples/TcpHelloWorld/TcpHelloWorld.ino) from the rosserial github.

To run the ros node use `roslaunch rosserial_server socket.launch`.

For `IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);` choose an IP for the arduino.

For `IPAddress server(192,168,0,11);` use your ip.

---

Originally posted by [Tim Nicolas](https://answers.ros.org/users/38875/tim-nicolas/) with karma: 16 on 2018-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0